# Proposition $5.2$, Section $2.3$ (Cyclic Groups) in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to give an alternative proof of a proposition in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra,* but I am unable to complete the details. The proposition is:

> \begin{align*}
> \text{Let $G$ be a group, and let $x \in G$ and let $a \in \mathbb{Z} — \{0\}$.}  \; \text{If}  \; |x| = n < \infty, \; \text{then} \; |x^a| = \frac{n}{(n,a)}
> \end{align*}

This is essentially Proposition 5.2 in section 2.3, *Cyclic Groups and Cyclic Subgroups*, on pp. 57. Here's my attempt:

Assume that $n \mid a$. Then $a = nk, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then. $x^a = x^{nk} = (x^n)^{k} = 1^k = 1$. Also noting that in this case $(n, a) = n$, we have that $|x^a| = 1 = n/(n,a)$.

Alternatively, assume that $n  \nmid a$. Then by the Divison Algorithm, we have that, $a = nq + r$, where $\; q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $0 < r < n$. Then, we have that,

\begin{align}
x^a = x^{nq + r} = x^{nq}x^r = (x^{n})^q x^r = 1(x^r) = x^r.
\end{align}

Assuming that $|x^a| = m$, we have that

\begin{align}
(x^a)^m = x^{am} = x^{rm} = 1.
\end{align}

This implies that $n \mid rm$. Since $n \nmid r$, we then must have that $n \mid m$, using a result in elementary number theory, which I think I have been able to prove on the side. I'll skip the details on this front.

I'm unable to proceed with the proof. I'm deliberately trying to prove the result without invoking/playing around with the expression given in the statement of the theorem. I'm trying to derive an expression, analogous to the one given in the statement of the theorem, using the Division Algorithm and divisibility theorems. I'm not so good with number theory, though.

Any hints?

Comment: It's pretty confusing if you use $n$ for something else than $\lvert x \rvert$ while the statement of the theorem supposes $\lvert x \rvert =n$.

Comment: @Demophilus Let me know where I may have used $n$ for something else. That must be a typo, I suppose.

Comment: I can't seem to find it anymore, I probably just misread. My apologies. I will give your question a shot.

Comment: @Demophilus Yes, I'm specifically trying not to use the statement of theorem as a useful guide to prove the theorem. If you read the proof in the textbook, the proof given over there use the given expression as a necessary guide to write the proof. While the expression may have been/can be (in principle) motivated in principle by considering various examples of finite groups and recognizing a pattern, I'm trying to motivate/deduce it based on number-theoretic considerations.

Comment: "Since $m<n$, we also have that $n\mid r$." This is incorrect. Consider the case $n = 6$, $r = 3$, $m = 2$. $6\mid 3\cdot 2 = 6$, and $2,3 < 6$, but $6$ divides neither $2$ nor $3$. If you knew that $(n,m) = 1$, you could conclude that $n\mid r$. Moreover, you cannot make the conclusion that $m < n$ in the first place: consider the case $G = \Bbb Z/(3)$, and $x = 1$, $a = 2$. $\left|x\right| = 3$, and $3$ does not divide $2$ (placing us in your second case), but $\left|1\right| = \left|2\right| = 3$ (both $1$ and $2$ are generators of $G$), and $3$ is not less than $3$.

Comment: @Stahl Sorry, there was a typo in that line. I have corrected it.

Comment: My counterexample still stands: $6$ divides $2\cdot 3$, but $6$ divides neither $2$ nor $3$. The general result is: if $(a,b) = 1$ and $a\mid bc$, then $a\mid c$. (Proof: there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ s.t. $ax + by = 1$. Then $acx + bcy = c$, and $a$ clearly divides both terms on the left, hence divides the sum, which is $c$.)

Comment: @Stahl Yes, I was just looking at that. :/

Comment: @Stahl Realized the mistake I made in my supposed proof of this assertion. Will give this approach to this theorem another attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not restrictive to assume $a>0$, as $|x^a|=|x^{-a}|$.

Let $y=x^a$. If $y^m=1$, then $n\mid am$, because $x^{am}=y^m=1$.

Conversely, if $n\mid am$, then $am=nq$ and
$$
y^m=x^{am}=x^{nq}=1
$$

In particular, $|y|$ is the minimal $m$ such that $n\mid am$.

If $d=\gcd(n,a)$, then $n=dn'$ and $a=da'$. Suppose $n\mid am$, so $am=nq$; then $da'm=dn'q$ and $a'm=n'q$. In particular $a'm=n'q$ is a common multiple of $a'$ and $n'$, hence a common multiple of $a'n'=\operatorname{lcm}(n',a')$, because $\gcd(n',a')=1$. Since $|y|$ is the minimal such $m$, we have $a'|y|=a'n'$. Therefore $|y|=n'=n/\gcd(n,a)$.